# XAMPP Tomcat Apache Connector

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, tomcat, xampp, connector

I am in the process of rebuilding my local development configuration and I am trying to install the tomcat connector so apache and tomcat talk to each other.  I have xampp and tomcat installed correctly and verified via safari.

I am using tomcat-connectors-current-src.tar.gz, unzipped to /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfilescustom/tomcatconnectors, I can configure the connector ./configure --with-apxs=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apxs however, when I go to use "make" in terminal I get a few odd errors at the very end of the process:

ld: unknown option: -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ld: unknown option: -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccs5y7FI.out (No such file or directory)
make[1]: *** [mod_jk.la] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

I am wondering if anyone knows whats up, or can point me to a blog entry that discusses how to accomplish this.  I have been searching for quite some time.

Yes, this is my first post on serverfault, i guess i can be called a serverfault noob, if I left out any information that may be needed to assist in troubleshooting this, please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I was using the wrong series of commands, after tons of research this series of steps unpacked and make the file correctly:

./configure --with-apxs=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apxs
cd apache-2.0
make -f Makefile.apxs install
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/modules
ls -l (verify that you have the mod_jk.so file)

Answer (score 1):

With Apache 2.2 (rather than 2.0) use mod_proxy_ajp and mod_proxy_balancer rather than mod_jk. These two modules come precompiled with XAMPP

See: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/miscellaneous/faq.html (look in the 'Does it work for Apache 2.2? section)